# Casting to object from a collection vs using foreach

Tags: c#

I am a little confused about the difference between the two statements.

This one works and prints out the property results just fine.

```
foreach( string key in result.Properties.PropertyNames )
{
    foreach( object property in result.Properties[key] )
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", key, property.ToString());
    }
}
```

and the following doesn't work. I thought by casting the specific property to object it would be the same thing but its obviously not:

```
foreach( string key in result.Properties.PropertyNames )
{
     if( key == "name" )
     {             
         Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", key, ((object)(result.Properties[key])).ToString() );            
     }
}
```

I get the object type of `result.Properties[key]` printed instead.

Comment: fyi you aren't passing a 2nd parameter to the `WriteLine` in the 2nd example.

Comment: yea typo.. I fixed it. Codes on a different computer so I couldn't copy paste it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two snippets do completely different things.

In the first example, `result.Properties[key]` is a collection of some sort (`IEnumerable`). It's looping through each object in the collection and printing the string representation of that object (`ToString()`) out to the screen.

In the second example, it's just printing the string representation of the collection itself, which often times is just the name of the type.
<sub>NOTE: You would almost never want `ToString` contain out the contents of the collection.</sub>

Comment: theres some missing code but it does compile.. I'm iterating through a search result from DirectorySearcher.

Comment: `((object) (key,result.Properties[key] ))` won't compile. You can't cast two things at once.

Comment: that bit should be
   
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", key, ((object)(result.Properties[key])).ToString() );

Comment: @Scott Please edit the question, rather than commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, even though `property` is type `object` in the first example, The actual property still has an underlying type that is being used for `ToString()`. You're just using the `object` type to hold a more derived type.

In the second example, where you cast it to type `object` you're telling the compiler "I don't care what type the property actually is, treat it like an `object` so it ends up using `object.ToString()` instead of `property.ToString()`.

Comment: But `ToString` is virtual, so it doesn't matter while the type of the variable is; all that matters is the type of the actual object at runtime.

Comment: @Servy the problem was I didn't understand what type was being returned. I thought it was a single object being returned not a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Properties is an object ith property names and per property name a set of values.
So... result.Properties[key] will return a ResultPropertyValueCollection, which contains one or more values.

You can enumerate through these values which you do in your first piece of code.

In your second example, your want to show all values in this collection. This can easily be done with LINQ. I split up the code for better understanding, but it can be written in one line:

```
foreach( string key in result.Properties.PropertyNames )
{
     if( key == "name" )
     {
         IEnumerable collection = result.Properties[key];
         string[] seperateValues = collection.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
         string joinedValues = String.Join(", ", seperateValues)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", key, joinedValues);             
     }
}
```

Comment: See the OP's edit from a while ago.  This change is needed to get the code to compile, but this is what the OP has actually been running from the start, and doesn't produce the desired results.

Comment: I'm iterating through a search result from DirectorySearcher. I've never used this library before. I am also somewhat new to C# and wanted to test if the two statements were equivalent to see if I completely understood what was going on.

Comment: No LINQ is needed at all.  The entire block of code can be replaced with: `Console.WriteLine("name:{0}", string.Join(", ", result.Properties["name"]));`

Comment: @Servy: You are right. I tested it under .NET Fx 3.5. The Join u are using exists since .NET Fx 4.0.